# OpenVPN client on Windows 7 - cannot add route from config script

Tags: windows-7, openvpn, route

I am connecting from my Windows 7 laptop to an openvpn server and I am unable to automatically add a route.
In my script I have the line:

route-up "route add 192.168.33.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.0.33.1"

but after the connection is set-up there is an error message:

```
Sat Feb 06 20:30:07 2010 us=974000 openvpn_execve: CreateProcess route failed: Cannot find file specified.   (errno=2)
Sat Feb 06 20:30:07 2010 us=989000 Route script failed: external program did not execute -- returned error code -1
```

The openvpn.exe is run as administrator.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ughh, finally found a solution (Windows-specific).

Put into OpenVPN client config the parameter:

```
script-security 2 system
```

---

The description from openvpn.net manual (https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn22ManPage) explains it:

> --script-security level [method]
>       This directive offers policy-level control over OpenVPN's usage of
>   external programs and scripts. Lower
>   level values are more restrictive,
>   higher values are more permissive.
>   Settings for level:
>
> ```
> 0 -- Strictly no calling of external programs.
> 1 -- (Default) Only call built-in executables such as ifconfig, ip, route, or netsh.
> 2 -- Allow calling of built-in executables and user-defined scripts.
> 3 -- Allow passwords to be passed to scripts via environmental variables
> (potentially unsafe).
> ```
>
> The method parameter indicates how OpenVPN should call external commands
>   and scripts. Settings for method:
>
> ```
> execve -- (default) Use execve() function on Unix family OSes and CreateProcess()
> on Windows.
> system -- Use system() function (deprecated and less safe since the external
> program command line is subject to shell expansion).
> ```
>
> The --script-security option was introduced in OpenVPN 2.1_rc9. For
>   configuration file compatibility with
>   previous OpenVPN versions, use:
>   `--script-security 3 system`

Answer (score 3):

better use:

route 192.168.33.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.33.1

this way route will be added and deleted when you connect and disconnect the vpn

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your OpenVNP client with run as Administrator Command for it to work.

Comment: this was the first thing I have tested. Unsuccessfully.
Looks like the route command cannot be executed anyway.
I gave it 'Everyone' read/execute permission - no luck :(